# uncaughtException Error: spawn /home/zn8zeklqieyf/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.1/bin/node EAGAIN (running godaddy terminal)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
zn8zeklqieyf@p3plmcpnl503622 [~/public_html]$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ yarn build:prebuild && next build
$ yarn build:fs && yarn build:search
$ node scripts/fs2json.js --exclude .index --out public/.index/fs.9p.json ./public && node scripts/preloadIcons.js
Creating file tree ...
Creating json ...
$ node scripts/searchIndex.js
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Creating an optimized production build
 ✓ Compiled successfully
uncaughtException Error: spawn /home/zn8zeklqieyf/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.1/bin/node EAGAIN
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -11,
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn /home/zn8zeklqieyf/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.1/bin/node',
  path: '/home/zn8zeklqieyf/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.1/bin/node',
  spawnargs: [
    '/home/zn8zeklqieyf/public_html/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
zn8zeklqieyf@p3plmcpnl503622 [~/public_html]$
```

I upgraded my plan to ensure the process doesn't reach 100%, but I am still getting the same error.